# How to make a loop to insert item in between all elements of an array

Tags: java, arrays

I have an an array [1,1,1,1,1,1] and I want to make a for loop that will insert a 0 in between all the 1s.

I’ve tried using

```
for(int i=0;i<array.length;i+2) {
    insertItem(array,i,0);
}
```

But this doesn’t work since the array increases in length every time you insert an item, and my client crashes.

Comment: Please, update the question with the code of `insertItem`

Comment: You could use an ArrayList<Integer> rather than an array, or you could use an array with the room for the extra characters in it.

Comment: You need to create a new array with room for the new items.

Comment: Does your initial array include only 1, or include mixed 0 and/or 1 like [1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming `insertItem` increases the length of `array` as needed. In that case the trick is to calculate the number of new insertions required (`array.length - 1`) before starting the loop. New values are inserted at odd locations, given by `2*i+1`

```
int n = array.length - 1;
for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
  insertItem(array, 2*i+1, 0);
}
```

An alternative would be to create a new array and populate it like this:

```
int[] narr = new int[2*arr.length-1];       
for(int i=0; i<narr.length; i++) {
    narr[i] = (i % 2 == 0) ? arr[i/2] : val;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a new array that is twice the length of the input, then loop through your input array and for each element, add it to the new array followed by a 0 updating an index as you go so that you are putting your 1s and 0s in the right position.

Not sure if you want a 0 at the end, if not adjust the details above accordingly (eg new array is twice size of input minus 1)

Comment: Twice minus one, e.g. `[1,1,1]` becomes `[1,0,1,0,1]`

Comment: Ha ha - spotted that at the same time as you :-)

Answer (score -2):

I think you just created an infinite loop. In your `for` loop, the `i+2` should be replaced by `i+=2`. If not, the condition will never be met.